# What's the difference between * and ?* in Veracity ignores?

Tags: version-control, wildcard, veracity

The examples show `cache/?*`, but I wonder why this strange combination, would the `cache/*` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're talking about Martin's comment on the [Ignore a file or folder](http://veracity-scm.com/qa/questions/92/ignore-a-file-or-folder/104) question.

He's suggesting that if you wanted to ignore a folder's contents (all files, subfolders), but still track the folder's existence (remember that Veracity actually tracks folders, rather than inferring their existence from files under them), you could use:

```
@/cache/?*
```

in your ignores list.  The difference is that just

```
@/cache/*
```

would match the `@/cache/` folder itself (`*` matches 0 or more characters).

`@/cache/?*` would only match files/folders under `cache`, since `?` matches any single character.  `@/cache/` wouldn't match, whereas `@/cache/a`, `@/cache/README`, etc. would.

Comment: Yes I was reading that question you mention. So I read it as /* means "folder and stuff from it", /?* means "only stuff". So how do you get "only folder name, no any stuff"?

Comment: Not possible. You can't exclude a folder while including its contents.